# Mongodb find created results by date today

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, meanjs

I have this query to get results on month. But I wanted to get the results of today.

```
var start = new Date(2010, 11, 1);
var end = new Date(2010, 11, 30);

db.posts.find({created_on: {$gte: start, $lt: end}});
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: `new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Your start date object should hold the current date time hours at `00:00:00.000` (milliseconds precision) and set the hours for today's date to `23:59:59.999`:

```
var start = new Date();
start.setHours(0,0,0,0);

var end = new Date();
end.setHours(23,59,59,999);
```

Then pass the modified date objects as usual in your MongoDB query operator:

```
db.posts.find({created_on: {$gte: start, $lt: end}});
```

If you are using the [dayjs date utility](https://day.js.org/) library, this can be done by using the [`startOf()`](https://day.js.org/docs/en/manipulate/start-of#docsNav) and [`endOf()`](https://day.js.org/docs/en/manipulate/end-of) methods on dayjs current date object, passing the string `'day'` as argument:

```
const start = dayjs().startOf('day'); // set to 12:00 am today
const end = dayjs().endOf('day'); // set to 23:59 pm today
```

---

You can also use [`$expr`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) as follows:

```
db.posts.find({
    $expr: {
        $eq: [
            { $dateToString: { format: '%Y-%m-%d', date: '$$NOW' } },
            { $dateToString: { format: '%Y-%m-%d', date: '$created_on' } },
        ],
    },
})
```

Comment: I had to use the .format() method on the dayjs object so the Mongo driver could handle it (I'm not using Mongoose). For example: const time = dayjs().startOf('day').format()

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

To find the today date results or data between dates, use the following:

**NodeJS:**

```
// Date format YYYY-MM-DD
// Suppose you want to look for 1 day data between 2021-12-27 00:00:00 and 2021-12-28 00:00:00
let start = new Date("2021-12-27");
let end = new Date("2021-12-28");

// "created_on" can be any field with a date 
db.posts.find({created_on: {$gte: start, $lt: end}});
```

This works on the **Mongo Shell** too:

```
db.posts.find({created_on: {$gte: new ISODate("2021-12-27T00:00:00.000Z"), $lt: new ISODate("2021-12-28T00:00:00.000Z")}})
```

Another Way:

```
// 27th half day
db.posts.find({created_on: {$gte: new Date("2021-12-27T00:00:00.000Z"), $lt: new Date("2021-12-27T12:00:00.000Z")}})
```

### Reference

> `find` - [Select / filter data](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find)
>
> `$gte` - [Greater Than / Equal](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte)
>
> `$lt` - [Lower Than](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lt)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get Today Start Date and End Date
  let startOfDay = new Date();
  startOfDay.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  let endOfDay = new Date();
  endOfDay.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);

  // Get Yesterday Start Date and End Date
  let startOfYesterday = new Date();
  startOfYesterday.setDate(startOfYesterday.getDate() - 1);
  startOfYesterday.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  let endOfYesterday = new Date();
  endOfYesterday.setDate(endOfYesterday.getDate() - 1);
  endOfYesterday.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);

  // Get Last Month Start Date and End Date
  let startOfPreviousMonth = new Date();
  startOfPreviousMonth.setMonth(startOfPreviousMonth.getMonth() - 1);
  startOfPreviousMonth.setDate(1);
  startOfPreviousMonth.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  let endOfPreviousMonth = new Date();
  endOfPreviousMonth.setMonth(endOfPreviousMonth.getMonth() - 1);
  let lastDayOfPreviousMonth = new Date(
    endOfPreviousMonth.getFullYear(),
    endOfPreviousMonth.getMonth() + 1,
    0
  );
  endOfPreviousMonth.setDate(lastDayOfPreviousMonth.getDate());
  endOfPreviousMonth.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
```