# "Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators" using MongoDB and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have below code which is working fine and displaying 100 records descending order of `Vote` value from `MongoDB` collection;

```
var myAggregate = Entry.aggregate([{ $group: { _id: "$url",author: { $first: "$author" }, vote: { $max: "$vote" }, url: { $first: "$url" }, title: { $first: "$title" } } },{ $sort:{ vote:-1} },{ $limit: 100 }]);

// Home Route
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  myAggregate.exec(function(err, entries) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err)
      } else {
          res.render('index', {
              entries: entries
          });
      }
  });
});
```

What i am trying to achieve is to filter this data based on today's date.

My schema looks like this;

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ec6efe565915b59f10787b4"
    },
    "title": "my title",
    "url": "https://myurl.com",
    "author": "john",
    "created": {
        "$date": "2020-05-22T00:17:14.340Z"
    },
    "vote": 51
}
```

My index page should display 100 records which are created **`today`**.

So for example if my entry is created within Today's date and time range then it should be displayed.

I tried to follow explanation on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327222/mongodb-find-created-results-by-date-today) question but did not work for me.I am receiving `Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators error`. Any idea what i am missing here?

```
var start = new Date();
start.setHours(0,0,0,0);

var end = new Date();
end.setHours(23,59,59,999); 

var myAggregate = Entry.aggregate([{ $group: { _id: "$url",author: { $first: "$author" }, vote: { $max: "$vote" }, url: { $first: "$url" }, title: { $first: "$title" } } },{ $sort:{ vote:-1} },{created: {$gte: start, $lt: end}},{ $limit: 100 }]);
```

Comment: `created` is your problem.

Comment: @ngShravil.py Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to take care:

1. `created` is neither an operator in aggregation pipeline nor an operator in MongoDB, I guess.

I assume that, you want to filter documents that fall with in the `start` and `end` range, you can replace this

```js
{created: {$gte: start, $lt: end}}
```

with

```js
{
  $match: {
    $expr: {
      $and: [
        {
          $gte: [
            "$created",
            start
          ]
        },
        {
          $lt: [
            "$created",
            end
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

2. After, carefully going through your query, I saw that you are missing `created` field in `$group` stage of your aggregation pipeline. Just add the below:

```js
created: {
  $first: "$created"
}
```

Comment: This gives me "unknown top level operator: $exper" error. Do you think i should use created[$date]?

Comment: There was a typo, I updated my answer. Just replace `$exper` with `$expr`.

Comment: Ok but this is not displaying any record. It is showing an empty page.

Comment: It might not be satisfying the range condition.

Comment: actually it's satisfying the condition, but still empty page.